# Laravel Eloquent: Passing the value of find() in a function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I probably didn't choose the most descriptive title but this is so hard to explain. I have an IPs table with a primary key of an unsigned integer, the ip address. Before storing an ip, I pass the ip through php's inet_* functions. When doing primary key looking in my model, IP, the ip passed in the `find()`method must be encoded to it's numerical value.

Here's an example of a lookup: `IP::find('10.0.2.2')` which should return a collection. However, it's being sent to a query as a string, not an integer. What I would like to happen in the background is this:

```
IP::find(inet_pton('10.0.2.2'))
```

without me needing to manually insert the function every time. I know, you must think I'm so lazy but I'm just trying to find the easiest way to do things because that's what programming is, right?

Here is my IP model:

```
class IP extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'ips';
    protected $connection = 'game';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ip';

    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function getIpAttribute($value) {

        return inet_ntop($value);

    }

    public function setIpAttribute($value) {

        $this->attributes['ip'] = inet_pton($value);

    }

    public function getUuidAttribute($value) {

        return bin2hex($value);

    }

    public function setUuidAttribute($value) {

        $this->attributes['UUID'] = hex2bin($value); 

    }

}
```

and here's the description of the table if you need:

```
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| UUID  | binary(16)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ip    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I'm going to be looking up ips to return the UUID of the user. Basically I'm trying to guess if they're browsing my website without logging in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just override the `find()` method:

```
class IP extends Eloquent {

    public static function find($id, $columns = array('*')) {
        return parent::find(inet_pton($id), $columns);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the find method:

```
class IP extends Eloquent {

    ...

    public find($key, $columns = array('*'))
    {
        if (filter_var($key, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
        {   
            $key = inet_pton($key);
        }

        return parent::find($key, $columns);
    } 

}
```